# A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List' Flutter Retrofit

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, retrofit, flutter-futurebuilder

so am trying to use the Retrofit package to auto generate my Rest Api Get request to return a listView of a url, name and id.
This is my code for the API request.

```
part 'api_request.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _RestClient;

  @GET("/data/{memes}")
  Future<List<Meme>> getMeme();
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Meme {
  String id;
  String name;
  String url;
  String box_count;

  Meme({required this.id, required this.name, required this.url, required this.box_count});

  factory Meme.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$MemeFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MemeToJson(this);
}
```

After running `flutter pub run build_runner build` in the terminal, I got the result below as the generated file.

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'api_request.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Meme _$MemeFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Meme(
      id: json['id'] as String,
      name: json['name'] as String,
      url: json['url'] as String,
      box_count: json['box_count'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$MemeToJson(Meme instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'name': instance.name,
      'url': instance.url,
      'box_count': instance.box_count,
    };

// **************************************************************************
// RetrofitGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class _RestClient implements RestClient {
  _RestClient(this._dio, {this.baseUrl}) {
    baseUrl ??= 'https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes';
  }

  final Dio _dio;

  String? baseUrl;

  @override
  Future<List<Meme>> getMeme() async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _headers = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _result = await _dio.fetch<List<dynamic>>(_setStreamType<List<Meme>>(
        Options(method: 'GET', headers: _headers, extra: _extra)
            .compose(_dio.options, '/data/{memes}',
                queryParameters: queryParameters, data: _data)
            .copyWith(baseUrl: baseUrl ?? _dio.options.baseUrl)));
    var value = _result.data!
        .map((dynamic i) => Meme.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    return value;
  }
```

So, the main error is in the main.dart file here, where I tried to store the snapshot data into List < Meme >  memes.. The error I got was:

> A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.  Try changing the type of the variable

```
FutureBuilder<List<Meme>> _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  final client = RestClient(Dio(BaseOptions(contentType: "application/json")));
  return FutureBuilder<List<Meme>>(
    future: client.getMeme(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Meme>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {

      List<Meme> memes = snapshot.data ;

        return _buildMemes(context, memes) ;
      } else if (snapshot.hasError){
        return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}');
      }
      else {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
}

Widget _buildMemes(BuildContext context, List<dynamic> memes) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: memes.length,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return Card(
        elevation: 4,
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(memes[index].name),
          leading: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(memes[index].url)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`List<Meme> memes = snapshot.data!;`
in `buildBody`

`snapshot.data` has the type `List<Meme>?` (a null safe type), you have to add `!` to make to use it with `List<Meme>`

Comment: Tried this and it removed the syntax error. I now have a runtime error. An image of the error in this link here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xv7yQaRbdEbPnC0TxKIPQUyjFR3P8Yzh/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

try List memes =[]  Flutter changed how they create lists because of the non nullable standard

Put the dio call as the future builder

Dio will return a response.data

Implement

_getdata() async
{

dio = Dio();
final response = await dio.get('https://your-endpoint.com');
return (response.data);

}

FutureBuilder<List>(
future: _getdata,
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {

```
  List<Meme> memes = snapshot.data ;

    return memes ;
  } else if (snapshot.hasError){
    return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}');
```

Comment: Tried this and it removed the syntax error too. I now have a runtime error. An image of the error in this link here [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xv7yQaRbdEbPnC0TxKIPQUyjFR3P8Yzh/view)

Comment: Don't use a future builder with dio.  Catch the dio promise -> then.   I will post how to use dio.